# Issue with Ionic (v1) app using listView and PouchDb

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app there is a listView with cards on which users can click. After clicking they should see a page with more details. All content is in a pouchDB database (and also remotely in Firebase). The code to generate this list is below:

```
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="challenge in vm.challenges track by $index" ng-class="{'bounceInLeft': $index % 2 !== 0, 'bounceInRight': $index % 2 === 0}" ng-click="vm.goToChallenge(challenge)">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <div class="resource">
                <img ng-src="{{ challenge.resources[0].image }}" ng-attr-alt="{{ challenge.resources[0].caption }}" ng-srcset="{{ challenge.resources[0].srcset }}" ng-if="challenge.resources && challenge.resources[0].type === 'img'">
                <img ng-src="{{ challenge.resources[0].url | getYouTubeImage }}" ng-attr-alt="{{ challenge.resources[0].caption }}" ng-if="challenge.resources && challenge.resources[0].type === 'video'">
                <i class="ion-play" ng-if="challenge.resources && challenge.resources[0].type === 'video'"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="category">{{ challenge.categoryName }}</p>
            <p class="name">{{ challenge.name }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item footer item-divider">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <i class="ion-calendar"></i> {{ challenge.seasonsObjects.join(', ') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <div>
                        <i class="ion-bookmark" ng-repeat="bookmark in (challenge.ranking + 1) | range track by $index"></i>
                    </div>
                    {{ challenge.rankingName }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, on an iPhone 5 (iOS 10.2) and Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (Android 4.4) clicking on a card does not show the details of that card (see image below). On an iPhone 5s and Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 5) this works correctly (see second image below).

[image: Empty screen - Details not shown]

[image: Working example]

The function goToChallenge is defined as follows in the controller:

```
vm.goToChallenge = (challenge) => {
    NavigationService.go('home.challenge', {
        challenge: challenge._id
    });
};
```

The NavigationService has the following code:

```
angular.module('starter').factory('NavigationService', ['$window', '$q', 'ionic', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', '$cordovaNativeAudio', '$cordovaSocialSharing', '$cordovaNetwork', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', '$ionicNavBarDelegate', '$ionicTabsDelegate', NavigationService]);

function NavigationService($window, $q, ionic, $state, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $cordovaNativeAudio, $cordovaSocialSharing, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicNavBarDelegate, $ionicTabsDelegate) {
let factory = {};
// Set root of history stack to the registration page with historyRoot: true
// Disable animation from slider to registration page to avoid weird transition
// in which the header bar pops down. This is because we do not have a header bar in the slider
factory.setRootAndGo = (state, params = {}) => {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        historyRoot: true,
        disableAnimate: true
    });
    factory.go(state, params);
};
factory.go = (state, params = {}) => {
    $state.go(state, params, {
        location: 'replace',
        reload: true
    });
};
factory.replace = (state, params = {}) => {
    $ionicHistory.currentView($ionicHistory.backView());
    factory.go(state, params);
};
factory.toggleMenu = () => $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
factory.showTabs = () => {
    $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(true);
};
factory.hideTabs = () => {
    $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(false);
};
factory.setTitle = (title) => $ionicNavBarDelegate.title(title);
factory.getParams = () => $state.params;
factory.getNavHistory = () => $ionicHistory.viewHistory();
factory.showLoading = (options) => $ionicLoading.show(options);
factory.hideLoading = () => $ionicLoading.hide();
factory.isWebView = () => ionic.Platform.isWebView();
factory.isOffline = () => factory.isWebView() && $cordovaNetwork.isOffline();
factory.goToWebPage = (url) => $window.open(url, '_system');
factory.shareFacebook = (text, img, url) => {
    let defer = $q.defer();
    $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(text, img, url)
        .then(defer.resolve, defer.reject);
    return defer.promise;
};
factory.shareTwitter = (text, img, url) => {
    let defer = $q.defer();
    $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaTwitter(text, img, url)
        .then(defer.resolve, defer.reject);
    return defer.promise;
};
factory.playSound = (name) => $cordovaNativeAudio.play(name);
factory.alert = (title, text) => $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: title,
    template: text
});
return factory;
};
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, please? I have been looking for a few days now and can't figure out why. Thanks!

**EDIT**

When I check with chrome://inspect in a virtual device (via Genymotion), I get the following error in the console

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'
> at ChallengeCtrl.vm.onAfterEnter (file:///android_asset/www/build/app.js:226:12)
> at m.$emit (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:178:407)
> at Object.q.emit (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:470:20592)
> at m (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:470:19062)
> at HTMLElement.g (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:470:18921)
> at Pf (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:70:477)
> at HTMLElement.Of.d (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:70:424) ionic.bundle.min.js:150

The onAfterEnter code block can be found below.

```
    vm.onAfterEnter = () => {
    //let ionViewDOM = $window.document.querySelectorAll('.challenge.pane .scroll-content')[0];
    let ionViewDOM = $window.innerHeight - 43;  // innerHeight minus the heigh of the title bar
    let popovers = $window.document.querySelectorAll('.message-popover');
    popovers.forEach((popover) => {
        //popover.style.height = `${ionViewDOM.clientHeight}px`;
        popover.style.height = ionViewDOM + `px`;
        if (ionViewDOM.clientHeight < 450) {
            popover.classList.add('small-screen');
        } else if (ionViewDOM.clientHeight < 550) {
            popover.classList.add('medium-screen');
        } else {
            popover.classList.remove('small-screen');
            popover.classList.remove('medium-screen');
        }
    });

    let params = NavigationService.getParams();
    ChallengeService.get(params.challenge)
        .then((result) => {
            vm.challenge = result;

            switch (vm.challenge.status) {
                case 'accepted':
                    vm.challengeAccepted = true;
                    break;
                case 'completed':
                    vm.challengeCompleted = true;
                    break;
            }
            NavigationService.setTitle(vm.challenge.gardenType.name);
            vm.challengeLoaded = true;

            ChallengeService.listRandomAvailableForUser(params.challenge, vm.challenge.gardenType.challenges)
                .then((result) => vm.randomChallenges = result);
        });
};
```

When I check in an iPhone 5 simulator (via XCode) I get the following similar error

> Error: popovers.forEach is not a function. (In 'popovers.forEach',
> 'popovers.forEach' is undefined)

So it has to do with the popovers. Could it be that `$window.document.querySelectorAll('.message-popover')` does not return anything? The div with the `message-popover` class are initially hidden on the page and only shown when a certain condition is met (with `ng-show`).

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors on the mentioned devices?

Comment: @bert did u tried with the crosswalk plugin for the android and test it in two device and let me know it went well or not

Comment: @Webruster, no have not tried that yet. But that would only solve the issue on Android and not on iPhone, I guess. The issue happens both on Android and iOS. So I guess it has to do with something else?

Comment: @BertCarremans , check in android and let me know, will provide a way to work in iOS

Comment: It seems that the error is for using a non-array object as array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your page is not completely rendered in those  case you reach the foreach error. have you tryed to set a timeout or similar before execute the querySelectorAll on the  page?